# Some anomaly in printing result for list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I have two list snip and phras. I tried to run them in for loop in two different ways. I was expecting them to give the same output but they are giving different. How so ?

```
snip = ['Hi john', 'Hi sam', 'Hi lila']
phras = ['lets play','lets paint']
for s in snip,phras:
     result = s[:]

print result   # output is ['lets play', 'lets paint']

# Now lets run again

snip = ['Hi john', 'Hi sam', 'Hi lila']
phras = ['lets play','lets paint']
for s in snip,phras:
     result = s[:]
     print result

#output is ['Hi john', 'Hi sam', 'Hi lila']
#          ['lets play','lets paint']
```

Comment: Your print statement is outside of your first loop so it only shows the last value of `result`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your print statement is outside of your first loop so it only shows the last value assigned to `result` whereas the second print statement is inside of the loop and therefore prints *each* value of `result`